# main.jsbundle is not getting updated

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, metro-bundler, watchman

I was getting  `cannot find main.jsbundle` error.

so i manually created bundle using
`react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios/'`

now again i was getting same error, so i manually added the main.jsbundle file via `Add files to project` option and now my build was successful but i am missing back button icon. also `the main.jsbundle` is not getting modified when is creating archive.

Someone please help me solve this issue.

Comment: I also was faced with a similar case recently. I tried a lot just not work! Finally, I create a new project and config the native code again to solve the problem.

Comment: Any updates? Were you able to solve it without recreating the project?